# Outputting character literal { to fstream C++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to write a part of a C++ file to output text to a file to be read by gnuPlot.
I want to include the characters { and } in my output file, so that gnuplot can read them in a style similar to that used by laTex.

The relevant section of my code reads

```
std::ofstream gnuplotFile2;
gnuplotFile2.open("FourierImages.gpi");
gnuplotFile2 << "set xlabel \"Wavenumber (m^" << '\\\u007B' << "-1" << '\} << "\"\n";
```

Here, I've used both \u007B and } to try and output { or }. I've also tried including just "...(m^{-1})\n"; and "...(m^\{-1\}\m";.

My output file always reads

```
set xlabel "Wavenumber (m^-1)"
```

which produces a graph/chart with the label having the - character in superscript, but the 1 as normal script.

How can I output the { and } characters to a file? I would like

```
set xlabel "Wavenumber (m^{-1})"
```

Comment: `plotfile << "set xlabel \"Wavenumber (m^{-1})\"\n"`; should work. Braces aren't special.

Comment: `'\\\u007B'`

This is not 1 character, so you must use double quotes:

`"\\\u007B"`

Comment: As a side comment, I'm wandering why you are using C++ to parse an output file? Though C++` could do such a thing and if its just for personal use, It would be better to use a language like **python**. I just think C++ is on the side of overkill for something like this, though others may differ. To each his own I guess

Comment: @chris You're quite right. After spending quite some time checking, running, editing, rerunning parts of code, writing this question, and thinking for about another twenty seconds, I came back here to try and delete my question - the code worked well but was editing the wrong file, and my example in the question referred to the correct file, whilst my actual code did not. Apologies.

Comment: @woosah The code I'm using does a few more things, but I didn't include the whole file since the stackoverflow help for 'code' tells me to indent it all by 4 spaces. Doing this with several hundred lines of code might be annoying, and indenting all of my code before copy-pasting it might leave strange indentation in the question. I also don't know how to use python (although clearly my C++ is also pretty poor) and learning more languages for simple tasks seemed inefficient (I'm using C++ to interface with OpenFOAM)

Comment: Are you saying that `<< "{-1}"` doesn't work for you? This is absolutely incredible. You either have a buggy standard library (highly unlikely) or don't show all relevant code.

Comment: You can just select an entire block of text/code and use the `{}` code formatting button to format it all at once.  No need to do it line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, just use the characters `{` and `}`, like this

```
$ cat test.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ofstream gnuplotFile2;
  gnuplotFile2.open("FourierImages.gpi");
  gnuplotFile2 << "set xlabel \"Wavenumber (m^{" << "-1" << "})\"\n";
}

$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out && cat FourierImages.gpi
set xlabel "Wavenumber (m^{-1})"
```